Access to mobile phone photo gallery from Blazor server app
There is a website (Blazor server). The client accesses it from his mobile phone, takes photos and videos of, say, an accident.
Can he send photos, videos to the server for recording in the database? Or do I need to make an app on phone for this?

Well, a custom application would in theory be far better, and far more seamless from a user experience point of view.
However, if you drop in a standard upload control into a web page, then when a user selects (hits) the file upload button, then the phone user is given options to select photos and files from their "picture gallery".
So, you can use a standard file up-load control. It not a great user experience compared to a custom application, but the answer is yes, users can upload files and videos much like a desktop user can choose files and pictures to upload.
